# About Modbus TCP request

Tags: python, networking, tcp, modbus-tcp

I have a question about modbus tcp request. There are two options in python for modbus tcp library. Auto_open and Auto_close, these are keep tcp connection open and open/close tcp connection for each request. Which one should I use? Which one is beneficial for Modbus Tcp devices? What is your suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Which of the Python Modbus libraries do you mean? Is it`pymodbus`?

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use Auto_close method and close port after each data transmission
this help you to connect more than one mocbus/tcp devices on same port(502).and the connection should be closed when you haven't data for transmitting